# What will this do? " cd /; ls -al > $HOME/outputfile.log "

Tags: linux, ls, cd-command, home

This was an exercise proposed to us in class' but I didn't get it. What exactly will these commands do?

```
cd / 
ls -al > $HOME/outputfile.log
```

---

I did try it (in Linux) but (apparently) nothing happened at least that I can see. I understand the commands `cd /`, `ls` and `-al`. I also know what `$HOME` means.

What I am struggling with is the following part:

```
> $HOME/outputfile.log
```

As in, what is this supposed to do?

I did `ls -al > outputfile.log` first and got permission denied, which I also understand. So what is the difference here?

Thanks guys.

Answer (score 0):

You did not say which Operation System. I will assume that it is Gnu/Linux with bash (however it should not matter).

I will not give answer, but will give you help in finding an answer (as it is clear  that your goal is to learn).

There are two commands. Look them up.

- `help cd` -- it is a shell built in, so you need to use `help`.
- `man ls`  -- not a shell built in, so you use `man`.

## looking up `>`

`man bash | less  "+/^REDIRECTION"`

## looking up `$HOME`

`man bash | less  "+/^[[:blank:]]+HOME"`

## looking up `$` -- variable expansion

Comment: Actually, `bash` is one of the few shells where that command would be incorrect as you need to quote word expansions in the target of redirections there.

Comment: See `info bash redirection` and `info bash HOME` as better ways  to get to the documentation (would also work with `zsh` in place of `bash`, as that syntax is more zsh-like than bash-like)

Comment: @StéphaneChazelas feel free to patch the answer.

Comment: @StéphaneChazelas I don't grok your first comment.

Comment: In `bash`, when interactive or when not in POSIX mode, you need to quote that `$HOME` unless you can guarantee it doesn't contain any character of `$IFS` or wildcards. IOW, `ls -al > $HOME/outputfile.log` is zsh syntax but not bash syntax. In bash, the equivalent is `ls -al > "$HOME/outputfile.log"` or `ls -al > ~/outputfile.log`.

Comment: Also note that `[[:blank:]]` is a shell glob operator so should be quoted.